# How to install NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.04

I'm trying to get Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit working on an old Dell Dimension 4300. I installed from a DVD and it installed fine except it was incredibly slow.

- I installed Compiz to remove window effects but it was still horribly slow.
- I installed `mesa-utils` to test if 3D acceleration was working, which it wasn't.
- I tried going to `System` -> `Software+updates` -> `additional drivers`, but that says no drivers are available.
- I tried going to NVIDIA's site for drivers and tried installing them from the terminal but I got an error complaining about `rmmod`'s path.
- I tried `sudo apt-get install nvidia-311` and got a similar error.

Its now booting into a black screen with no user feedback.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it done on Lenovo Y500 laptop.

Download either [32 bit](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/331.49/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-331.49.run) or [64 bit](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/331.49/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.49.run) driver depending on your architecture.

First make sure that remove any previous driver install, using `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`.

Once you're logged in, Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, to switch to the first virtual terminal and login. Once logged in, navigate to where the file was downloaded, and do the command(s) below:

```
sudo service lightdm stop 
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-*-331.49.run
sudo sh ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-*-331.49.run
```

Once done, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to GUI, and reboot.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but I'm currently booting into a black screen that I don't know how to avoid.  I've read that 12.04 will auto install proprietary video drivers, so I'm thinking I may try that next

Answer (score 0):

Use Nvidia Drivers from PPA (easy install):

Type `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` and type `sudo apt-get install nvidia-331-updates nvidia-settings-updates`